# How can I set the value of my MaterialUI TextField to uppercase?

Tags: reactjs, input, material-ui, styles, textfield

I have a Material UI TextField as an input and I need to force the entered text as uppercase. I have tried using `textTransform: "uppercase"` as part of the style attribute but this does not seem to work. All of the other styling in my component is applied correctly however the textTransform is not.

I have also tried using the standard style method of passing my style as a prop to the component but I get the same result.

My component:

```
  const MenuInput = (props) => {
  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    input: {
      textTransform: "uppercase",
      marginTop: "10px",
      width: "100%",
      borderRadius: 4,
      backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
    },
  }));

  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <TextField
      className={classes.input}
      id={props.id}
      color="primary"
      label={props.label}
      variant="filled"
      onChange={(e) => props.onChange(e)}
      error={props.isError}
      helperText={props.error}
    />
  );
};
```

The output:

[image: Output of TextFields]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could try applying styles through the `inputProps` like the following:

```js
 <TextField
      className={classes.input}
      id={props.id}
      color="primary"
      label={props.label}
      variant="filled"
      onChange={(e) => props.onChange(e)}
      error={props.isError}
      helperText={props.error}
      inputProps={{ style: { textTransform: "uppercase" } }}
/>
```

I'll leave a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-lake-hzs8o?file=/src/App.js) with a sandbox where I tested that solution.

Comment: Just what I needed thanks, so is the input prop for styling specifically for the input field?

Comment: Yes, you can specify props for the `input` component (`TextField`'s child).

Comment: This is not valid, because of what chrishawn said in the below answer...

Answer (score 9):

important to note just changing the style does not change the actual state value sent to onChange. This will only DISPLAY uppercase but the data saved will still be the original lowercase etc.

Answer (score 1):

Changing styles doesn't change actual value.
You can check it here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/textfield-uppercase-material-ui-forked-nhkzpn

If you want to uppercase the value, you can do it in onChange event:

```
  const MenuInput = (props) => {
  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    input: {
      textTransform: "uppercase",
      marginTop: "10px",
      width: "100%",
      borderRadius: 4,
      backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
    },
  }));
  const [val, setVal] = useState(props.value);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setVal(e.target.value.toUpperCase());
    props.onChange(e)
  }
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <TextField
      className={classes.input}
      id={props.id}
      value={val}
      color="primary"
      label={props.label}
      variant="filled"
      onChange={handleChange}
      error={props.isError}
      helperText={props.error}
    />
  );
};
```

or do it more general and pass a function to onChange event, so you can do any transformation. You can also pass this function as a prop to your MenuItem component.

```
  const MenuInput = (props) => {
  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    input: {
      textTransform: "uppercase",
      marginTop: "10px",
      width: "100%",
      borderRadius: 4,
      backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
    },
  }));
  const [val, setVal] = useState(props.value);
  const transormFn = (s) => s.toUpperCase();
  const handleChange = (e, fn) => {
    if (fn) setVal(fn(e.target.value));
    props.onChange(e)
  }
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <TextField
      className={classes.input}
      id={props.id}
      value={val}
      color="primary"
      label={props.label}
      variant="filled"
      onChange={e => handleChange(e, transformFn)}
      error={props.isError}
      helperText={props.error}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding important
textTransform: "uppercase !important"

Or add inline style
<Textfield style={{textTransform:"uppercase"}} />